# Are AJAX calls processed in serial fashion on server if you use ASP.Net session state?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, session

While reading 70-486 reference book, I came across a paragraph which seems incorrect to me.

> "The design of session state, as implemented in ASP.NET, implies that
>   only one request from a particular user’s session occurs at a time.
>   This means that if you have a page that includes multiple, independent
>   AJAX callbacks happening at once, these calls will be processed in
>   serial fashion on the server. If your application is sessionless, it
>   can also handle AJAX callbacks in parallel rather than requiring that
>   the work be performed in serial, which enables you to perform
>   multiple, simultaneous AJAX calls from the client."

May I have your thoughts on this? I was knowing that AJAX calls are always parallel irrespective of the session or state.

Answer (score 4):

This statement is completely true. ASP.NET Session is not thread safe and doesn't allow parallel requests from the same session. It blocks them and executes sequentially.

AJAX requests are parallel except that they are coming from the same session (same ASPSession cookie being sent to the server), so the server will simply block them and execute sequentially. So basically you send parallel requests from the client, but the server will not process them in parallel.

That's one of the reasons why the very first thing I when I start an ASP.NET application is to ensure that the Session is completely disabled in web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="Off" />
```

Comment: I have created two `generic http handlers` and called them through `jQuery` asynchronously in my project. When I put break-point to them I see the parallel request processing. Does it mean Parallel processing?

Comment: If you are not using session inside those handlers then it will be parallel processing.

Comment: But I implement the interface `IRequiresSessionState` and using session variable in that handlers.

Comment: Oh, then you've got a problem. The handler will block requests from the same session and execute them sequentially. It's as simple as that.