# Why is Application_ResolveRequestCache have a long duration?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, performance, caching

I have an ASP.NET application with a trace (log) tool.
It uses AJAX for retrieving data (controls).
I have those two trace entries:

```
    protected void Application_ResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Log("Application_ResolveRequestCache", null);
    }

    protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Log("Application_AcquireRequestState");
    }
```

Time diff between these two entries is duration of `Application_ResolveRequestCache` (i think). Method `Log` depends on singleton class, which writes in `HttpContext.Current.Trace`

Example: user do something on page, for that site sends 5 AJAX requests (updates 5 controls) to server.
Duration of `Application_ResolveRequestCache` for each request is (in order by time): 0.001, 1.518, 4.556, 5.057, and 5.575 (in seconds).

In my Global.asax i have disabled cache via filters:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new OutputCacheAttribute
            {
                VaryByParam = "*",
                Duration = 0,
                NoStore = true,
            });
        }
```

**So, why Application_ResolveRequestCache takes time even output cache is disabled?**

note: current issue only for AJAX requests.

additional information:

AJAX query:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/mvcget/ajax/LoadControl/",
            data: properties,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            async: true
        });
```

LoadControl action:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult LoadControl()
        {
            var control = CreateControlFromRequest<ITemplatedControl>();
            control.SaveUserValues();
            var content = control.Render();
            return Content(String.IsNullOrEmpty(content) ? " " : content);
        }
```

Comment: just a not: what is the requirement of using such display picture for ur profile it is not good in SO

Comment: I like it.. Well formatted question too so shouldnt' really matter.

Comment: thanx for changing the display picture :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test code isn't measuring the time it takes simply to invoke ResolveRequestCache.  Instead, it's measuring the time it takes to invoke everything between ResolveRequestCache and AcquireRequestState.

If you're making parallel requests to the server and if those requests contain a Session cookie, the ASP.NET runtime will serialize the requests.  The time spent holding these requests in the pipeline would show up between the ResolveRequestCache and AcquireRequestState method invocations.

See [Are AJAX calls processed in serial fashion on server if you use ASP.Net session state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560631/are-ajax-calls-processed-in-serial-fashion-on-server-if-you-use-asp-net-session) for more information on AJAX + Session.

Edit: I should mention that a few other events (such as Routing) occur between ResolveRequestCache and AcquireRequestState.  If you have many routes defined or if the route matching logic is particularly complicated, this would also contribute to increased time spent.

If you're going for accurate performance measurements in your web application, take a look at http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/tracing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i can't find information about Routing event. Can you explain?

Comment: ASP.NET Routing is the component that matches the incoming URL to the controller that will eventually be used to service the request.  These routes are generally defined in RouteConfig.cs or Global.asax.  See http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.90).aspx for a general overview of Routing.  The Routing core logic (which matches URLs with endpoints) runs between ResolveRequestCache and AcquireRequestState.